# How to define variable in class component

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 basic components here and I get an error when trying to map over my elements:

```
class EleMenu extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <li className="eleMenu">{this.props.name}</li>
    )
  }
}

class MainMenu extends Component {
  const rows = []
  this.props.elements.forEach()    //error here
    (e) => {
      rows.push(
        <EleMenu
          name={e.name}
        > 
        <EleMenu/>
      )
    }
  );

  render(){
    return (
      <ul className="mainMenu">
        {rows}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

It says unexpected token for the line: `this.props.elements.forEach()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reason is, only methods are allowed inside es classes and you have defined const and running loop also.

This is in proposal stage **[check this](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields)**.

**Solution:**

Either put all the code inside a function and call that function from render method like this:

```
class MainMenu extends Component {

  renderElement() {
    const rows = []
    this.props.elements.forEach(e => {
      rows.push(
        <EleMenu
          name={e.name}
        > 
        <EleMenu/>
      )}
    )
    return rows;
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <ul className="mainMenu">
        {this.renderElement()}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Or put all the code inside render method:

```
class MainMenu extends Component {

  render(){
    const rows = []
    this.props.elements.forEach(e => {
      rows.push(
        <EleMenu
          name={e.name}
        > 
        <EleMenu/>
      )}
    )

    return (
      <ul className="mainMenu">
        {rows}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

**Suggestion:**

Better to use [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), instead of using forEach and then pushing the elements inside an array.

Like this:

```
class MainMenu extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="mainMenu">
        {
          this.props.elements.map(e => (
            <EleMenu
              key={e.name}
              name={e.name}
            /> 
          ))
        }
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume he is still not going to display li items as he wants since no .map() on rows isn't he?

Comment: Component is returning rows which will be rendered in return statement.